# Angular 4 - ngModel expression as number

Tags: angular

Would it be possible to set expression for ngModel as number? Something like this:

> [(ngModel)]="coeffHour.01"

With this I have following error:

> Parser Error: Unexpected token '0.01' at column 10 in [coeffHour.01] in ng:///AdministrationModule/CoefficientsHourComponent.html@27:48 ("name="01" required type="number" min="0" step="0.1"
>                              formControlName="01" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="coeffHour.01">

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `coeffHour.01` is not valid JS. If you want your object to have a numeric property, you need to do `coeffHour[01]`

Comment: what is the value of coeffHour.01?

Comment: @bugs That is what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[(ngModel)]` will not take numbers in it.

You need to use it like :

```
[(ngModel)]="coeffHour[01]"
```